# Vue: how to have conditional slot components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an array of 10 `items` that have half of them with the `type: 'Normal'` and the other half with the `type: 'Variant'`.  I am trying to pass them into `MyComponent` and then slot in `Component1` if the type is `Normal` and slot in `Component2` if the `type` is `Variant`.

I am having an issue because I keep getting `Component1` slotted in all 10 times though instead of half `Component1` and half `Component2`

**Parent**

```
 <MyComponent :items="items">
    <template v-slot="slotProps">
      <Component1
        v-if="slotProps.item.type === 'Normal'"
      />
      <Component2
        v-if="slotProps.item.type === 'Variant'"
        :class="$style.gridCover"
      />
    </template>
  </MyComponent>
```

**MyComponent.vue**

```
   <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <div
          :key="index"
          :class="$style.gridItem"
        >
          <slot :item="item"></slot>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make two name slot in **MyComponent.vue**
2. And Then use `v-if` inside **MyComponent.vue**, not in Parent